# Use of undeclared identifier 'UnityCurrentMTLCommandEncoder'

Tags: ios, ipad, unity-game-engine

I'm using Toon Boom Harmony and Unity (2017.2), when i build to iOS 11.1 using xcode i get the following error:

Use of undeclared identifier **'UnityCurrentMTLCommandEncoder'**

Use of undeclared identifier **'UnityEndCurrentMTLCommandEncoder'**

```
static int registerCallbacks()
{
    HarmonySetGetMetalBundleFunc(&UnityGetMetalBundle);
    HarmonySetGetMetalDeviceFunc(&UnityGetMetalDevice);
    HarmonySetCurrentMTLCommandEncoderFunc(&UnityCurrentMTLCommandEncoder); // Error
    HarmySetEndCurrentMTLCommandEncoder(&UnityCurrentEndMTLCommandEncoder); // Error
    HarmonySetCurrentMTLCommandBufferFunc(&UnityCurrentMTLCommandBuffer);
    HarmonySetGetMetalCommandQueueFunc(&UnityGetMetalCommandQueue);
    return 0;
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the framework you are using is not swift 4 compatible.